# default login url on HttpUnauthorizedResult in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, custom-attributes

I have written a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` which has the following condition in asp.net mvc3 application:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{     
    //auth failed, redirect to Sign In
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

And in my web.config, i have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/SignIn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

On authentication fail, it redirects to "/Account/Login" page by default.

How do i change this default redirect url and redirect it to "/User/SignIn"?

The screenshot shows the clear view of what i am trying to say..[image: HttpUnauthorizedresult image]

Though i have set '/User/SignIn', it redirects to '/Account/Login'

Comment: I got the solution after a struggle. I have added WebMatrix.WebData reference recently, which seems to be the real culprit of this issue. This can be handled by adding the key to your config file: <add key="loginUrl" value="~/User/SignIn" />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure whether i can add this as an answer. But this may help others who were having this related issue.

I got the solution after a struggle. I have added WebMatrix.WebData reference recently, which seems to be the real culprit of this issue. This can be handled by adding the key to your config file:

```
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/User/SignIn" />
```

Comment: The key should be added to the appSettings section in your web.config.

Comment: I think we normally add the keys like above to appSettings section :)

Comment: @Prasad I already spent a couple of hours on this... Thanks a bunch for posting back here and saving the rest of my day!

Answer (score 2):

You should be modifying the root one for loginUrl.

i have created AuthorizationAttribute... it's redirecting properly 
e.g.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Authenticate/SignIn" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

and my attribute is:

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

and apply attribute to any method of your controller as necessary...

```
[AuthorizationAttribute()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have changed it in root config. But it was redirecting to /Acccount/Login page and throws 404 page, as i dont have such controller.

Comment: That's strange since i have peformed POC on this just now to verify and it's working as expected redirecting to Action specified in web.conf (root one)...

Comment: Can you post the Customer Authorize Attribute code to cross check whether i am missing anything?

Comment: i have updaed my answer and posted the code for you but it's exactly the same as your Attribute... no magic...

Comment: The code is same, but i am confused whats the problem with my application. I am using Framework 4.0, MVC 3..

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and found it was because I had the WebMatrix.dll referenced in my project.

Removing this DLL fixed the issue

see here
[What is the PreserveLoginUrl appSetting key/value in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321843/what-is-the-preserveloginurl-appsetting-key-value-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)