# Where does MVC3 redirect unauthorized users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, authorization, forms-authentication

So I have an ASP.NET MVC3 app with the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  ....
  <system.web>
  ....
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~" 
            slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080" />
    </authentication>
```

and a controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public class MetaStyleController : TunaController
{
    ....
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ....
```

If I'm not logged in, and I try to hit `http//localhost/myAppPath/MetaStyle` , I get redirected to the log on page, as defined above, right?

So why am I getting redirected to `http://localhost/myAppPath/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmyAppPath%2fMetaStyle`? (notice, the url has ***Login*** rather than ***LogOn***)

Where is `Login` coming from? I don't see it in my project.

Comment: Do you see a valid page at that URL?

Comment: Spender, see if this post from John Galloway helps: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: So we're searching for the Login phantom :) My guess is for overlapping web.config files in parent/child directories... The account/login should be defined somewhere...

Comment: @Colombo (great name, btw!) There's nothing at that url.

Comment: I would do a solution wide search for text "Login" to find the culprit. :-)

Comment: No dice. First thing I tried... it just ain't there (although I may have missed it, but I'm loathe to check for the 6th time!)

Comment: are you really looking at the correct web.config for the website? reload the file from disk. also check your routes

Comment: possible duplicate of [default login url on HttpUnauthorizedResult in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015464/default-login-url-on-httpunauthorizedresult-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I've marked my own question as a dupe after I found someone here facing exactly the same problem. It seems that after adding deployable assemblies to the project, WebMatrix has been mysteriously added, which screws up the redirect mechanism. Poor show Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

See [ASP.NET MVC 3 Release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230). According it you should use following app setting.

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```