# What is the PreserveLoginUrl appSetting key/value in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I was reviewing some `ASP.NET MVC` code, specifically a web.config  file.

I noticed this in the `appSettings` section:

`<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />`

1. What does this do?
2. When was it introduced to ASP.NET MVC?

cheers!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [MVC 4 Whitepaper](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes):

> When WebMatrix.WebData.dll is included in in the /bin directory of an ASP.NET MVC 4 apps, it takes over the URL for forms authentication. Adding the WebMatrix.WebData.dll assembly to your application (for example, by selecting "ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax" when using the Add Deployable Dependencies dialog) will override the authentication login redirect to /account/logon rather than /account/login as expected by the default ASP.NET MVC Account Controller. To prevent this behavior and use the URL specified already in the authentication section of web.config, you can add an appSetting called PreserveLoginUrl and set it to true

Comment: Cheers! and why would we want the `WebMatrix.WebData.dll` in our /bin directory?

Comment: I think that's for when you create a Web Pages application using [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/webmatrix/asp.aspx), or when you add [Web Pages as Deployable Dependency](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/2011-03-23-bin-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-visual-studio) in an MVC project. I don't know why the setting gets included for a default MVC app. The [assembly contains membership and security classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538450(v=vs.111).aspx) that can also be used in MVC.

Comment: Is it relevant for MVC5 apps? Thanks

Comment: in .net core template, is this setting available?